# Google Language Translator not in the Wordpress plugin repository

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using Google Language Translator on my wordpress website. I noticed that there is a new version since a few days ago.

But the plugin is no longer in the Wordpress plugin repository.

Why is this? Does it mean it has security problems? 
Should I take it off?

(creator of plugin: http://studio88design.com/wordpress-plugins/google-language-translator/)

Comment: try to reinstall plugin.

Comment: that doesnt solve my question

Answer (score 0):

After release of version 5.0.11, the author (that's me) had his Wordpress.org account hacked, which prompted Wordpress.org to de-list the plugin temporarily.  However, Wordpress and the developer worked out the issues and the plugin has been relisted.

Most current version is 5.0.22 at time of this answer.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-language-translator/